# SharePoint 2016 - Direct link to edit Wiki page?

Tags: hyperlink, wiki, wiki-pages, edit

I have an .aspx file (says "Infos.aspx") based on the [WikiPage template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sptemplatefiletype.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and created in the */Site Pages/* list.

I would like to add an Edit button with a custom link on the homepage of the site that get us on the "Edit" page immediately. Currently, I only redirect to the aspx file itself and I have to click on the "Edit" links in the top right corner of the page if I want to change its content, but it adds an extra, and annoying, step.

Is this even possible? I tried with GET/POST parameters but with no chance.